# Can't debug Go programs in VS Code on Mac OS but have the right arch and HOSTOS

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I saw that question multiple times and tried all I can to solve it with the given answers, but it seems it is something else..

I installed the arm64-Version of Go as mentioned in every answer about that question. I have a Macbook with Apple M1-Chip.

Darwin/arm64 is installed, and I can also build a go program in terminal and run it through the terminal, but doing it with fn + f5 gives me that error:

"Failed to launch: could not launch process: can not run under Rosetta, check that the installed build of Go is right for your CPU architecture"

My go env Is like that:

```
GO111MODULE="off"
GOARCH="arm64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/myName/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/myName/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/myName/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/myName/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch arm64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/jt/r0dd0zvj0jv0jfmdbmxxszqw0000gn/T/go-build3752056080=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

How is that wrong? I mean, it's buildable by terminal so it should be fixable somehow, right?

Comment: I would guess your VS Code app is amd64. Alternatively, you have both Go arm64 and amd64 installed and your using the former when using the `go` command in a terminal and the latter inside VS Code due to differences in the PATH.

Comment: @KurtisRader I have the Apple-version of VS Code ( at least Silicon says that ) and uninstalled every Go version + installed the arm64 version only. I don't guess it has to do with these things sadly..

Comment: Can you check if you can debug with dlv directly e.g. `dlv debug` from the terminal? And check if `dlv` is compiled for the right arch? (e.g. `objdump -h <path_to_dlv>`) If not, see if deleting dlv and reinstalling it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have an M1, a use the insiders-edition of VSC (for arm)
I have go version go1.18 darwin/arm64
I have dlv version
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.8.1
Build: $Id: d85f1f6b736db99a1c239c34fd4a081dcff08a3c

It only complains about Rosetta if the apllication runs on Intel.
So one of those if NOT arm.
Did you have a previous AMD installation? Are you sure that's gone?

Comment: Yes, this is good advice. I found that I can use the `file` command in the terminal to track down what happened. Apparently VS Code installed the amd64 version for me, unhelpfully, via the bottom status bar Go menu. After fixing all the versions back, now the output of `file $(which dlv)` should be something like `/opt/homebrew/bin/dlv: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64` (note arm64), and `file $(which go)` gives `/usr/local/go/bin/go: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64`.